# Background worker run worker completed

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

depending on the do work method my result could either be a List of Strings or a list of byte[]

How can we check the `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e` -

```
if (e is List<String>)
```

is this the correct way to check?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's one possible way to do it.

If you only have two types it would be quite easy:

```
if(e.Result is List<string>)
{
}
else if(e.Result is List<byte[]>)
{
}
else
{
}
```

But the problem comes in to play if you have to support more than just two or three. In that case i'm going to create a `Dictionary<Type, Action<object>>` and write individual functions for each type. Something like this:

```
var supportedTypes = new Dictionary<Type, Action<object>>();
supportedTypes.Add(typeof(List<string>), ComputeListOfStrings);
supportedTypes.Add(typeof(List<byte[]>), ComputeListOfByteArrays);

private void ComputeListOfString(object listOfStrings)
{
    var list = (List<string>)listOfStrings;
}

private void ComputeListOfByteArrays(object listOfByteArrays)
{
    var list = (List<byte[]>)listOfByteArrays;
}
```

This makes it more simple to support new types and also stays to be O(1) while the `if-else-if` runs into the order-matters problem.

Used will this in your background worker as followed:

```
worker.OnRunWorkerCompleted += (sender, e) =>
{
    Action<object> supportedAction;

    supportedTypes.TryGetValue(e.Result.GetType(), out supportedAction);

    if(supportedAction != null)
    {
        supportedAction();
    }
};
```

Comment: should that not always derive to false seeing as e actualy is RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs though?

Comment: @rik: Yes, but i though that this was an error in the question. I think it should be [`RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs.Result`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.componentmodel.runworkercompletedeventargs.result.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not the right way.
The correct way is to use this:

```
if(e.Result is List<string>)
{
    //...
}
else if(e.Result is List<byte[]>)
{
    //...
}
else
{
    //...
}
```

`e` will always be of type `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs`. But this class contains a property `Result` that contains the result of your `DoWork` event handler. That's the one, you need to check.

Answer (score 0):

the e.Result is the property with your results, so to get the type you can do:

```
if(e.Result.GetType().Equals(typeof(List<String>)))
```